# dynamic styling and filtering of a geoserver wms using openlayers.layer.wms.post with legend

Tags: openlayers, extjs3, geoserver, wms

I have defined a WMS.Post layer in a map as suggested [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/dynamic-styling-and-filtering-of-a-geoserver-wms-using-openlayers-layer-wms-post/) for dynamic styling porposes because I have a parametric filter dependent from the feature of the WMS layer I asked for.
The problem is that I need to setup a legend inside a LegendPanel GeoExt object. I see that when the legend panel asks for the legend to geoserver the service is called with a GET method and when the given sld style is too long the call fails. How can I force the panel to use a POST method?

This is how my legendPanel is defined:

```
var legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    title: "Legenda",
    bodyStyle: "padding:5px",
    labelCls: "mylabel",
    split: true,
    map: map,
    region: "center",
    autoScroll: true
});
```

Thank you for any help

M.

Comment: just pin this link that gave me my friend Simone that seams to solve. I'll report if it will solve my quest.
[http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/URL-Too-Long-for-GetLegendGraphics-WMS-Get-Request-td4481884.html](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/URL-Too-Long-for-GetLegendGraphics-WMS-Get-Request-td4481884.html)